# Страница не видит $ при подключенном Jquery, в чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос такой, снизу страницы подключен jq, но код не хочет работать. Так же пробовал подключать над кодом, толку не дало. Притом что на другой странице этот же код работает. В чем может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: **Вангую**, что JQ подключен ниже, чем скрипт который обращается к JQ. Расположите подключение JQ в `head` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @De.Minov, не помогает

Comment: @Духсообщества,  у меня есть скрипт на jq, снизу него подключается сам jq через cdn, но ничего не работает. Пишет, что не понимает что такое "$". Пробовал подключать над этим скриптом, ошибка не решается

Comment: Тогда требуется больше информации. P.s. Духсообщества - бот

Comment: @kochurinn уберите defer у jquery и скриптов подключаемых через него. А сам jquery поместите в head. Для jquery дурной тон использовать defer и async

Answer (score 0):

Разверни в ошибках, что там покажет:
[image: вот]